# How can I speed up my AWS RDS Postgres performance?

Tags: ruby, performance, postgresql, amazon-web-services, sinatra

I just set up a db.t2.micro instance on Amazon's AWS. I am using sinatra to load a localhost webpage. I am using Active Record to do maybe about 30~ queries and it's taking 92 seconds to load. It's extremely slow. I tried doing custom parameters as listed here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_BestPractices.html#CHAP_BestPractices.PostgreSQL

This didn't help speed anything up. I'm not sure how I can speed up this instance. This is my first time hosting a database. Any help would be appreciated.

When I run my sinatra app it host locally(localhost). Here is where the 30~ queries are taking 92 seconds to load. When I run select * statements in Postgres they take only a couple seconds.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by *"It is only slow running through localhost. When I do queries in Postgres it is very fast."*? Are you saying that the database is too slow, or is it "very fast"? Also, please note that the `t2.micro` instance has burstable CPU -- if the CPU is used too much, it will slow down. Have you looked at the [CloudWatch metrics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/rds-metricscollected.html) to see whether CPU/RAM/Disk is constrained?

Comment: It would be useful to do some logging to see whether the slow-down is caused by the database or the app. It would also be useful to see a log of the SQL queries sent to PostgreSQL to see which ones might be running 'slow': https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_LogAccess.Concepts.PostgreSQL.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is the latency between you and Amazon's data center.

For example, when you are in New York and your RDS instance is in Amazon's data center on the West Coast, then the latency between you and the data center is about 80-100ms. That means when your local application sends a query to the database, then it takes about 100ms before the database receives the query. To return the answer, it takes again an additional 100ms.

That said: Assume a roundtrip including computation takes 300ms, and you have ~30 queries, then your application loses about 10 seconds doing nothing – just waiting for data being sent through the wire. And there are other factors that might slow down this even more: Big packets or lost packets (the server has to ask again), bad internet connections, wireless connections, the distance between you and the database being longer than my example.

Therefore, the database should be as near as possible to the application server in the same data center to minimize latency.